# Fill empty row when have one id record on summary query in Mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

Good afternoon, i want to ask about MySql query.

I have the initial data as pict below.

[image: initial datas]

I want to calculate the number of hours difference by displaying several data columns with the MySql query below.

```
SELECT id AS id,beacon_name AS Name,MIN(received_date) as tap_in,MAX(received_date) as tap_out,TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,MIN(received_date),MAX(received_date)) AS work_hours from tb_gate_log where date(received_date) ='2023-06-06' group by id;
```

and it works like pict below.

[image: result]

however, there are cases such as there is only one data with status only "OUT" or "IN" for one id. I want the result like pict below when have status "Out" or "IN" only in one id.
[image]

how i do the query with result i wanted?

thank you,

regards.

Comment: It sounds like you need a table with all possible values, then `LEFT JOIN` from that table to your table.  You may also need a `COALESCE` to turn `NULL` into `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT id AS id,
  beacon_name AS Name,
  MIN(case when status = 'IN' then received_date end) as tap_in,
  MAX(case when status = 'OUT' then received_date end) as tap_out,
  COALESCE(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,
    MIN(case when status = 'IN' then received_date end),
    MAX(case when status = 'OUT' then received_date end)), 0) AS work_hours 
from tb_gate_log 
where date(received_date) ='2023-06-06' 
group by id
;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Great,thank you so much sir.